# How to animate round stat bar with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, progress-bar, loading, progress

I'm trying to find a way to fill in a circular red statistic bar with jQuery when the page loads. It would start black and fill in red in a circular motion. It doesn't have to have anything to do with the actual number, the number won't reflect the amount it fills. I'm trying to get all the bars to fill to the same point.

This is a preview of what I'm trying to accomplish but in a circular motion. - http://www.designfluxx.com/labs/bars/

Here is an image preview of the round stats circles - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh1mL.jpg

Comment: Try the following jsfiddle. This might help you. 

http://jsfiddle.net/oskar/Aapn8/

Comment: @Doink - That looks like an answer to me, post it and you will get some upvotes!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a ***modified* version** of the answer given in the comments above: http://jsfiddle.net/mnbishop017/XJWhW/ (Original fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oskar/Aapn8/)

This will give you an **interactive SVG file** in the web browser. You can modify the code to fit your needs.

#### HTML:

```
<input id="range" type="range" min="0" max="100" />
<canvas id="counter" width="240" height="240"></canvas>
```

#### CSS:

```
body {
    text-align:center;
}
canvas {
    display: block;
}
input {
    width: 200px;
}
```

#### JavaScript:

```
var range = document.id('range');
var bg = document.id('counter');
var ctx = ctx = bg.getContext('2d');
var imd = null;
var circ = Math.PI * 2;
var quart = Math.PI / 2;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = '#005075';
ctx.lineCap = 'round';        // can also be 'square'
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
ctx.lineWidth = 10.0;

imd = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 240, 240);

var draw = function(current) {
    ctx.putImageData(imd, 0, 0);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(120, 120, 70, -(quart), ((circ) * current) - quart, false);
    ctx.stroke();
}

range.addEvents({
    mousemove: function() {
        draw(this.value / 100);
    }
});

var myFx = new Fx({
    duration: 8000,
    transition: 'bounce:out',
    onStep: function(step){
        draw(step / 100);
        range.set('value', step);
    }
});

myFx.set = function(now){
    var ret = Fx.prototype.set.call(this, now);
    this.fireEvent('step', now);
    return ret;
};

myFx.start(0, 100);
```